# How to suppress output

Tags: powershell, r, batch-file

I would like to suppress output in R when I run my R script from the command prompt.

I tried numerous options including `--slave` and `--vanilla`. Those options lessens the amount of text outputted.

I also tried to pipe the output to `NUL` but that didn't help.

Comment: Maybe R is printing to stderr if `> NUL` doesn't help. Try appending `2>&1` as well.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Look at  `help(sink)` to do that.  On Unix I'd do

```
sink("/dev/null")    # now suppresses
....                 # do stuff
sink()               # to undo prior suppression, back to normal now
```

and the Windows equivalent (with a tip-of-the-hat to Johannes) is

```
sink("NUL")
....
sink()
```

Comment: Usually the Windows equivalent is `NUL`. However, it may well be that `CreateFile`, &c. won't be able to open it and that it's largely special functionality in the shell which enables its workings.

Comment: Thank you -- I edited the answer accordingly (after testing that it does indeed work that way with `NUL` quoted properly).

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel, I noted that this doesn't for dumping errors from try() sections, sink(file="NUL", type="message") complains that "NUL" isn't a file connection, in those cases one needs to use the try(stop("error msg"), silent=TRUE) for it to work as expected. Just wanted to add this to your answer in case anyone else stumbles upon this answer.

Comment: So, is there a universal (platform independent) way to achieve this other than simply supplying a `tempfile()`?

Answer (score 3):

Since R (>= 3.6.0), [there exists](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.10.1/topics/nullfile) a platform-independent alternative to [Dirk Eddelbuettel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501913/5363942). Simply type

```
sink(nullfile())    # suppress output
....                # your code
sink()              # end suppressing output
```

to suppress output on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: If including this in a function, then can wrap inside `on.exit(sink())`  - otherwise unexpected errors in the function may leave you wondering why you have no output to the console.