# Suppress output of a function

Tags: r

I'm looking to suppress the output of **one** command (in this case, the `apply` function).

Is it possible to do this without using `sink()`?  I've found the described solution below, but would like to do this in one line if possible.

[How to suppress output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501895/how-to-suppress-output-in-r)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'do this inline'?  Otherwise the question you cite already provides the answer and this is a duplicate.

Comment: This solution requires three lines, one redirecting output, the command, and then another to turn output back on.

Comment: Or use `capture.output`.  Or use `*_ply` from the plyr package.

Comment: I second Hadley's suggestion- if you are really trying to execute an apply function, such as `lapply`, without printing output then 'l_ply` from his `plyr` package is probably the most appropriate choice.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It isn't clear why you want to do this without `sink`, but you can wrap any commands in the `invisible()` function and it will suppress the output.  For instance:

```
1:10 # prints output
invisible(1:10) # hides it
```

Otherwise, you can always combine things into one line with a semicolon and parentheses:

```
{ sink("/dev/null"); ....; sink(); }
```

Comment: Try 'invisible(cat("Hi\n"))' -- `invisible()` only suppresses the print of an expression, it is not a `sink()` one-liner.

Comment: Right, but I think that it meets the needs of the questioner, unless I'm missing something in the question...

Comment: For instance, this suppresses the return of `apply`, as per the question: `invisible(apply(matrix(1:10), 1, as.numeric))`.

Comment: Rather than `{ sink("/dev/null"); ....; sink(); }` I would definitely prefer `capture.output`, as `capture.output` effectively does exactly above, just a lot better (have a look at the source, it calls sink as in above fashion, plus some nice stuff around it).

Comment: doesn't work on `idw` function under Windows. I think the best solution is using `sink`

Answer (score 73):

Use the `capture.output()` function. It works very much like a one-off `sink()` and unlike `invisible()`, it can suppress more than just print messages. Set the `file` argument to `"/dev/null"` on UNIX or `"NUL"` on windows, or, better, use `nullfile()` (>= 3.6.0) for platform independence. If you need to support R< 3.6, use `R.utils::nullfile()`. For example, considering Dirk's note:

```
> invisible(cat("Hi\n"))
Hi

> capture.output(cat("Hi\n"), file = nullfile())
>
```

Comment: doesn't work if you want to apply this to a function which returns some value and you want to use this value

Comment: @TMS Did something change during the last few month? I just tested to use the value returned by a function and it worked... `capture.output(x <- log(2))` and afterwards `x` has the value of `log(2)`...

Comment: This did not work for output in red.

Comment: using `nullfile()` in your code is probably cleaner than platform-specific nullfile()/NUL ?

Comment: Works alright! Actually for a ggplot I also combined afterwards a ```suppressMessages``` to hide it completely

Answer (score 31):

The following function should do what you want exactly:

```
hush=function(code){
  sink("NUL") # use /dev/null in UNIX
  tmp = code
  sink()
  return(tmp)
}
```

For example with the function here:

```
foo=function(){
  print("BAR!")
  return(42)
}
```

running

```
x = hush(foo())
```

Will assign 42 to x but will not print "BAR!" to STDOUT

Note than in a UNIX OS you will need to replace "NUL" with "/dev/null"

Comment: This was the only answer that did what I needed, underrated.

Comment: exactly what i needed too

Comment: This did not work for me, still getting red letters output

Comment: @SkyScraper - Can you please give a short toy example of what you're doing that causes this to fail?

Comment: @Danny I figured out the issue, the output was messages() and this approach does not function for this kind of output. I had to use `suppressMessages()`

Answer (score 11):

R only automatically prints the output of unassigned expressions, so just assign the result of the `apply` to a variable, and it won't get printed.

Comment: Some functions have a `print()` or `cat()` in them that goes to the screen, not to an assignment.

Answer (score 11):

you can use 'capture.output' like below. This allows you to use the data later:

```
log <- capture.output({
  test <- CensReg.SMN(cc=cc,x=x,y=y, nu=NULL, type="Normal")
})

test$betas
```

Comment: This did not work for output in red.

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone's arriving here looking for a solution applicable to RMarkdown, this will suppress all output:

````
```{r error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
invisible({capture.output({

# Your code goes here
2 * 2
# etc
# etc


})})
```
````

The code will run, but the output will **not** be printed to the HTML document

Answer (score 0):

```
invisible(cat("Dataset: ", dataset, fill = TRUE))
invisible(cat(" Width: " ,width, fill = TRUE))
invisible(cat(" Bin1:  " ,bin1interval, fill = TRUE))
invisible(cat(" Bin2:  " ,bin2interval, fill = TRUE))
invisible(cat(" Bin3:  " ,bin3interval, fill = TRUE))
```

produces output without NULL at the end of the line or on the next line

```
Dataset:  17 19 26 29 31 32 34 45 47 51 52 59 60 62 63
Width:  15.33333

Bin1:   17 32.33333
Bin2:   32.33333 47.66667
Bin3:   47.66667 63
```

Answer (score 0):

Making Hadley's comment to an answer: Use of apply family without printing is possible with use of the `plyr` package

```r
x <- 1:2
lapply(x, function(x) x + 1)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 3

plyr::l_ply(x, function(x) x + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that is robust to errors in the code to be shushed:

```
quietly <- function(x) {
  sink("/dev/null") # on Windows (?) instead use `sink("NUL")`
  tryCatch(suppressMessages(x), finally = sink())
}
```

- This is based directly on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2723115/18796807), for which thanks.
- But it avoids leaving output silenced if an error occurs in the quieted code.

Comment: OP asked for an answer which leaves out `sink`.

Comment: OP accepted an answer which works via `sink`. 

This answer updates the accepted answer to avoid a pitfall arising if an error occurs in the code the answer is applied to.

Comment: If your answer enhances an existing accepted answer its better practice to suggest an edit to that answer or suggest it as a comment below the answer. Regardless of what OP accepts, the answers provided should answer the question which is asked. Stack Overflow is a community. If someone else has the same question, wanting to avoid `sink` it will be marked as duplicate even though this question does not have an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering how to suppress a `warning()` you can use `suppressWarnings()` like so:

```r
suppressWarnings(warning("hi"))
```

Whereas these two will still show the warning:

```
invisible(warning("Hi"))
# shows 'Hi'

capture.output(warning("Hi"), file='NUL')
# shows 'Hi'
```

Answer (score 0):

for the return(something) part inside an R function:

```
return(invisible(something))
```

works ok

```
invisible(return(something))
```

does not work at all