# Suppressing messages in Knitr / Rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Here is the code for my RMarkdown file:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
opts_chunk$set(comment = NA, echo=FALSE, message = FALSE, warnings = FALSE)
options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
Sys.setenv(TZ = "GMT")
library(quantmod)
library(xtable)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
```

```{r}
getSymbols("^RUT")
chart.TimeSeries(RUT)
dev.off()
```
````

Despite settings `message = FALSE, warnings = FALSE`, I am still getting output messages in the HTML file when I run `getSymbols()` and `dev.off()`.  Their respective outputs are:

```
[1] "RUT"
```

and

```
null device 
          1
```

How do I suppress these messages?

Comment: This answered my problem with a error that wouldn't be suppressed
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978427/suppressing-error-messages-in-knitr

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using `invisible` to suppress those types of output.

````
```{r}
invisible(getSymbols("^RUT"))
chart.TimeSeries(RUT)
invisible(dev.off())
```
````

From the help page for `?invisible`:

> This function can be useful when it is desired to have functions return values which can be assigned, but which do not print when they are not assigned.

Neither of these are "messages" or "warnings", but actual output values. You'll see that the *messages* for `getSymbols` are, indeed, suppressed by knitr in the output.

Comment: Still looking for a way to suppress warnings for ggplot calls. Wrapping ggplot call into invisible suppress the image as well, which is kind of counter productive. :)

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem with using "ksvm". Unfortunately, "invisible" does not work.

Comment: Worth adding this `invisible` solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61571259/4083743, the benefit is that you can wrap certain lines of code in a chunk using `invisible` and `capture.output` - meaning you dont have to wrap everything

Answer (score 45):

Ran into this problem as well, I would like to add that it should be `warning = FALSE,` not `warnings = FALSE`

Answer (score 40):

You should never need to use `dev.off()` when using `knitr`. It takes care of all the devices to create plots.

From the package author [Yihui](http://yihui.name/en/2012/06/enjoyable-reproducible-research/)

[image: God kills a kitten whenever you dev.off()]

```
null device 
          1
```

Is the output of `dev.off()`.

It may be that `getSymbols` returns something given that you haven't defined `env`

If you want to hide the results (`output`) (in general) you can use `results = 'hide'` as an option. No need to wrap anything in `invisible()`

Comment: +1 I didn't know that tidbit of information about `dev.off()` and knitr. Thanks!

Comment: please be sure to include my kitten poster when you see `dev.off()`: http://yihui.name/en/2012/06/enjoyable-reproducible-research/

Comment: @yihui - I was searching for that kitten poster (without success). I've included it now.

Comment: but what if you want to output an image to a file so you can use it elsewhere? What's the alternative to dev.off()?

Comment: @Nova I was looking for that question as well. If you are fine with exporting all figures to a folder (which I think `rmarkdown::render` does by default) you can add a general settings option like `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = c('png', 'pdf'),fig.path='figures/')` where in dev you specify which output formats you need.