# Suppressing Error Messages in knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

I wonder how to suppress error messages in `knitr`. My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
<< Test >>=
1:10
X
@ 
\end{document}
```

**Edited**

The object `X` does not exist. I want to show `X` in my code chunk and want to evaluate it too even this will throw an error. But doesn't want to show any errors in my `.tex` document same as we can suppress warnings by setting `warning=FALSE`.

Comment: Yes X does not exist and will produce error. I don't want to show any error message in my knitr file.

Comment: Yes I want to show `X` in my code chunk and want to evaluate it too. But doesn't want to show any errors as we can suppress warnings by setting `warning=FALSE`.

Comment: Try `error=FALSE`, but your goal is not fully clear for me.

Comment: OP just wants to have the code run, without showing the errors, how is this unclear?

Comment: It would appear `include` chunk option fails when there is an error in the chunk. I hope @Yihui will chime in if it's possible to stop the chunk from appearing in the result no matter what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Errors have their own dedicated hook function, stored in the environment accessed by `knit_hooks$get()`.  Here, for your enlightenment, is the complete list of those functions:

```
names(knit_hooks$get())
# [1] "source"   "output"   "warning"  "message"  "error"    "plot"    
# [7] "inline"   "chunk"    "document"
```

To suppress warnings, just overwrite the default error hook function with one that takes the required arguments, but doesn't return anything at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
muffleError <- function(x,options) {}
knit_hooks$set(error=muffleError)
@

<<Test>>=
1:10
X
@
\end{document}
```

Which, upon compilation, yields the following

[image]