# Error handling within Sexpr

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch, knitr

How do I permit errors within `\Sexpr`?

I have a knitr document. A small part of this document refers to a file that cannot be shared. So whenever `\Sexpr{a}` is called on for some object `a` that depends on that file being read, it returns an error. I'd like instead for `\Sexpr` to print that it encountered an error.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for red

\begin{document}

<<>>=
x <- 1
@

The value of $x$ is \Sexpr{x}

<<>>=
a <- scan("secret_file.txt")
@
The value of $a$ is \Sexpr{a}.

\end{document}
```

will not compile (when `secret_file.txt` isn't present). I'd like the output to look something like:[image: Sexpr-error-detected]

I thought that altering the `inline` hook would work, but putting the following chunk made no difference.

```
<<Sexpr-setup>>=
library(knitr)
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x){
  out <- tryCatch(
    {
      if (is.numeric(x)) 
        x = round(x, getOption("digits"))
      paste(as.character(x), collapse = ", ")
    }, 
    error = function(cond){
      return("\\textcolor{red}{\\textbf{Sexpr error!}}")
      invisible(NULL)
    }, 
    warning = function(cond){
      return("\\textcolor{red}{\\textbf{Sexpr warning!}}")
      invisible(NULL)
    }
  )
  return(out)
})
@
```

It is not essential to have a custom error message, only that errors are clear from the output and do not prevent compilation. I appreciate that I could do a find replace into something like `\Sexpr{XX(` and define a function upfront `XX()` that does the same `tryCatch` maneouvre, but I thought [`knitr` could do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11072652/1664978).

---

Calling `knitr::knit` on the above and applying the traceback shows that:

```
11: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
10: eval(parse_only(code[i]), envir = envir)
9: withVisible(eval(parse_only(code[i]), envir = envir))
8: inline_exec(block)
7: in_dir(opts_knit$get("root.dir") %n% input_dir(), inline_exec(block))
6: call_inline(x)
5: process_group.inline(group)
4: process_group(group)
3: withCallingHandlers(if (tangle) process_tangle(group) else process_group(group), 
       error = function(e) {
           setwd(wd)
           cat(res, sep = "\n", file = output %n% "")
           message("Quitting from lines ", paste(current_lines(i), 
               collapse = "-"), " (", knit_concord$get("infile"), 
               ") ")
       })
2: process_file(text, output)
1: knitr::knit("knitr-prevent-errors.Rnw", quiet = TRUE)
```

From following the functions, it appears that the error is low down at

```
eval(parse_only(code[i]), envir = envir)
```

Where `code[i]` is `a`. Am I right in thinking that the only way to resolve this is to change the line starting `v =` with a `tryCatch`?

Comment: Not sure whether the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978427/suppressing-error-messages-in-knitr) could be adapted to your problem.  The answer by Josh O'Brien changes the error hook function.  The knitr documentation [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/) suggest that this hook handles the errors for both chunks and inline code. `error: errors from stop() (applies to errors in both code chunks and inline R code)`.  I had a quick play with adding `knit_hooks$set(error=myErrorFunction)` with your code but I still couldn't get it to compile with `\Sexpr{a}`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that will only work for in-chunk options

Answer (score 5):

With the option `include=FALSE` in the setup chunk,the following worked for me with output as below. If it does not work for you I will delete the post

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for red


<<setup, include=FALSE>>= 
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {

out <- tryCatch(
    {
      if (is.numeric(x)) 
        x = round(x, getOption("digits"))
      paste(as.character(x), collapse = ", ")
    }, 
    error = function(cond){
      return("\\textcolor{red}{\\textbf{Sexpr error!}}")
      invisible(NULL)
    }, 
    warning = function(cond){
      return("\\textcolor{red}{\\textbf{Sexpr warning!}}")
      invisible(NULL)
    }
  )

return(out)

})
@ 



\begin{document}

<<>>=
x <- 1
@

The value of $x$ is \Sexpr{x}

<<>>=
a <- scan("secret_file.txt")
@
The value of $a$ is \Sexpr{a}.

\end{document}
```

**Knitr Output:**

```
>knitr::knit("test.Rnw")


processing file: test.Rnw
  |.........                                                        |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...................                                              |  29%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 2
 $ include: logi FALSE
 $ indent : chr "    "

  |............................                                     |  43%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.....................................                            |  57%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ indent: chr "    "

  |..............................................                   |  71%
   inline R code fragments

  |........................................................         |  86%
label: unnamed-chunk-2 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ indent: chr "    "

  |.................................................................| 100%
   inline R code fragments


output file: test.tex

[1] "test.tex"
```

**Tex Output:**

```
>texi2pdf("test.tex")
>
```

I am using MikTex 2.9,knitr 1.9, R 3.0.2 on Windows , can you please attach your log files then we can compare the differences if any

Comment: So I didn't get it to compile, but I'd like to explore this a bit more.  What do you get when you `knitr::knit` your file?

Comment: How are you getting this to work without `library(knitr)` in `test.Rnw`?

Comment: Sorry I did not mention. In RStudio 0.95.551, I do `library(knitr)` first and then `knit("test.Rnw")`. Are you trying to compile the file from commandline