# Suppressing error message from heatmap.2 in knitr/Rmarkdown

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I am trying to generate a plot using `heatmap.2` and print to a pdf_document using Rmarkdown.

Whether I call `heatmap.2` from the console or in an .Rmd, the plot appears perfectly exactly as I want it. But additionally, I receive the error message:

```
## Error in plot.new(): figure margins too large
```

I can force knitr to continue processing using `error=TRUE`, but the error message is still printed. I also have set

```
echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE
```

which I thought would suppress the message, but it doesn't. I have tried using `invisible()` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406028/suppressing-messages-in-knitr-rmarkdown), but it seems to do nothing.

I have also tried "fixing" the error by adjusting my plot parameters in `heatmap.2` with no success-- it seems to complain when one of my columns in `lhei` is too skinny. Since the plot looks fine, I am not worried about it unless there is no other way to suppress this error message.

How can I suppress this error message in my Rmarkdown pdf?

Comment: I can't test this without seeing your code / markdown script, but you could try wrapping your plot call in `try(...,silent=TRUE)`, e.g. `try(<function_producing_error_message>,silent=TRUE)`.

Comment: It worked! If you want to leave an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty robust way of suppressing error messages is to wrap an expression in `try(...,silent=TRUE)`. As a general example, if we use the following code to set up a plot layout

```
plotIDs <- matrix(c(1:16), 4, 4, byrow = T)
layout(plotIDs, widths = c(0.5,1,1,1,1), heights = c(0.5,1,1,1,1))
```

calling `frame()` afterwards will produce an error:

```
R> frame()
Error in frame() : figure margins too large
```

Wrapping this with `try`, i.e.

```
R> try(frame(),silent=TRUE)
R>
```

will not produce an error message in the console.