# Suppressing output in slidify if neither "invisible()", "echo=F", "warning=F" or "error=F" work?

Tags: r, r-markdown, slidify, kernlab

I want to suppress the message "Setting default kernel parameters", but none of the options discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406028/suppressing-messages-in-knitr-rmarkdown/40174213#comment67615765_40174213) are doing the job that is "echo=F", "warning=F", "message=F" or the use of "invisible".

[image]

[image]

What else can I do? The info-string really disturbs the layout of my slides, when I am doing the above commands in a k-fold cross-validation loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workaround:

```
ksvm(Class ~. data = dat.train.df, kernel = "vanilladot", kpar=list())
```

This suppresses the message.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solves my problem, which is very good. However, I would still like to understand the general phenomenon.