# Is there a way to prevent line break in the HTML when results='hide' and echo=FALSE?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

In R, using knitr, is there a way to prevent line breaks in the HTML when results='hide' and echo=FALSE?

In this case:

````
First I do this, 
```{r results='hide', echo=FALSE}
x=4;x
```
then I do that.
````

I get:

```
First I do this,

then I do that.
```

with both a break and an extra line between.

I'd like to get:

```
First I do this, then I do that.
```

instead.

Generally speaking, I'd like for code chunks to not insert new lines so that markdown is free to eat the one after the first line of text.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're creating an HTML document from an R Markdown document. In that case, you can use the inline R code capability offered by `knitr` by using the ` characters starting with the letter r.

Example:

In your R Markdown, write:

```
First I do this,`r x=4` then I do that. I can call x by doing `r x`.
```

And as output, you get:

> First I do this, then I do that. I can call x by doing 4.

Note that in my example, I evaluated the variable `x`, but if you do not want to evaluate it, you do not have to. The variable `x` should still be assigned a value of `4` from the

```
`r x=4`
```

part of the R Markdown.

This is *Inline R Code*, and is documented [here](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/using_markdown) under the section "**Inline R Code**".

EDIT:

Note that Inline R Code has properties that are analogous to "`echo=FALSE`". And if you want to hide the results from inline R code, you can use base R functions to hide the output. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723034/howto-suppress-one-commands-output-in-r).

Comment: x=4 is not actually the code that I want to place there.  Assuming the insertion of arbitrary code that will be echoed and have its own output that I need to suppress, I believe that I need to use the three-backtick approach so that I have access to the echo and results chunk options.

Comment: @softboyled Your example was not very clear on that point. I believe my answer gives the result you requested in your question. Can you clarify your question with a better example that outlines what you want to achieve?

Comment: Agreed. Inline code is the only way to go, as far as I see. At the moment, there is no easy way to suppress the empty line if you use code chunks (three backticks).

Comment: @ialm: The question and text both state: "when results='hide' and echo=FALSE" which cannot be done in your scenario.

Comment: @softboyled I took the example provided in your question and created the desired output, albeit using a different construct than you originally proposed to arrive at the result. I apologize if the solution does not work for you, but if you have a better example of what result you want, then there may be better solutions offered by others. BTW, @Yihui is the creator of `knitr`, maybe you can bug him now that he's here :)

Comment: @iaim Thanks for the tip, but that's not quite what I'm after.  I think that it's a 'bug' in the rstudio code.  Looking into it...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

````
``` {r , results="asis", echo=F, eval=T} 
if(showMe){
  cat("printed")
} else {
  cat("<!-- no break line -->")
}
```
````