# Null output when printing heatmap.2 object in rmarkdown

Tags: r, heatmap, r-markdown, gplots

I'm using `rmarkdown` via `R-Studio` and want to plot a `heatmap` by the `heatmap.2`. When I change the angle of column labels via the `strCol` option I get a `NULL`  message printed before the `heatmap` in the output PDF file.
Attached a minimal code reproduce the problem:

```
{r, message=FALSE,warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
require(gplots)
data(mtcars)
x  <- as.matrix(mtcars)
heatmap.2(x,srtCol=0)
```

The PDF look like

[image]

Is there any way to remove this `NULL` from the PDF output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following modification using `capture.output`.  This did not print `NULL` for me.

````
```{r, message=FALSE,warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
require(gplots)
data(mtcars)
x  <- as.matrix(mtcars)
res <- capture.output(heatmap.2(x,srtCol=0))
```
````

There may be a better way with some option to `heatmap.2` but I didn't see it in the documentation.  This was based off of the following SO post [Suppress one command's output in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723034/suppress-one-commands-output-in-r).