# knitr, suppress nms stress from vegan metaMDS

Tags: r, knitr, vegan

I want to knitr a report with NMS ordinations. I'd like to include the code in the report but not the Run stress.

I've tried `message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='hide'` but it's still being included in the report.

```
bc.nms <- metaMDS(as.dist(bc), k=2, trymin=50, trymax=500, wascores=F)

## Run 0 stress 0.2484634 
## Run 1 stress 0.2548965 
## Run 2 stress 0.2660619 
## Run 3 stress 0.2471903 
## ... New best solution
## ... Procrustes: rmse 0.07881697  max resid 0.198888 
## Run 4 stress 0.2515325 
## Run 5 stress 0.2456675 
## ... New best solution
## ... Procrustes: rmse 0.04504745  max resid 0.2189408 
## Run 6 stress 0.2563108
```

I want just

```
bc.nms <- metaMDS(as.dist(bc), k=2, trymin=50, trymax=500, wascores=F)
```

If it helps figure out how to suppress the unwanted results, here is my knitr options and a screen shot of my report

`output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true # table of content true
    depth: 3  # upto three depths of headings (specified by #, ## and ###)
    self_contained: yes`

[image]

UPDATE. sorry should have included using the vegan dataset instead.

```
install.packages("vegan")
library(vegan)
data(dune)
bc.nms <- metaMDS(dune, k=2, trymin=50, trymax=500)
```

the solution within vegan is more direct than capture.output (which also works)

```
bc.nms <- metaMDS(dune, k=2, trymin=50, trymax=500, trace=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723034/suppress-one-commands-output-in-r), you can try:

```
capture.output(bc.nms <- metaMDS(as.dist(mtcars), k=2, trymin=50, trymax=500, wascores=F), file='NUL')
```

I get warnings as I am just using the `mtcars` dataset, not sure if you do but you can use `options(warn=-1)` beforehand to suppress them as well.

Comment: `trace = FALSE` suppresses tracing of calculations and silences `metaMDS` (and `trace = 2` is even more voluminous than the default). The argument `trace` is documented, and I suggest that you consider reading documentation if everything else fails in the future.

Comment: I had no idea what "Trace the function; trace = 2 or higher will be more voluminous." meant till this comment.