# Disable and enable output in R

Tags: r, io

Is there a way to prevent a command from printing any output?

I was using the `nnet` function from the package with the same name and it printed some information that I didn't need, making noise in the output of my own program. I found out that with the parameter `trace=FALSE` the function would run quietly, but now I'm wondering what would happen if a function didn't accept such an argument.

In other words, would it be possible to temporarily disable the output in R?

**Edit**

To be more specific, I mean the standard output, the one you have with `print`. For example, something like this:

```
print("a")
disable_output()
print("b")
enable_output()
print("c")
```

with the following output:

```
[1] "a"
[1] "c"
```

Comment: `? suppressMessages`    `?suppressPackageStartupMessages` `?suppressWarnings`

Comment: I deleted my answer. Why? Based on the updated explanation your question is answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723034/suppress-output-of-a-function
see Danny's answers using sink()

Comment: @Technophobe01 Thanks!

Comment: +1 to @Technophobe01 for the suggestion! Anyway pay particular attention to use sink() out of functions and/or without protect yourself from against whatever could happen while the sink is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can divert output globally only to a file (I do not know if you can completely disable it). You can look at `?sink` as a starting point.

On the other hand, you can use:

`?capture.output`: Evaluates its arguments with the output being returned as a character string or sent to a file.

and

`?invisible`: Return a (temporarily) invisible copy of an object.

To write a function which evaluates its arguments without throwing any (standard) output (note, it could be useful to include `?force` in the function's body to force the evaluation of its argument):

```r
invisible(capture.output(print("foo")))

without_output <- function(x) {
    invisible(capture.output(force(x)))
}

without_output(print("foo"))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS          
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Europe/Rome                 
#>  date     2020-09-07                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  backports     1.1.9   2020-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  callr         3.4.3   2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  devtools      2.3.1   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  knitr         1.29    2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  processx      3.4.3   2020-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ps            1.3.4   2020-08-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rlang         0.4.7   2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.3     2020-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringi       1.4.6   2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  usethis       1.6.1   2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  withr         2.2.0   2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  xfun          0.16    2020-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#> 
#> [1] /home/cl/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0
#> [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#> [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#> [4] /usr/lib/R/library
```