# How to suppress RED progress messages that are not warning messages? SOLUTIONS NOT WORKING

Tags: r, output, suppress, suppressmessage

I have a script and in that script I am running a command form a package: proteinToGenome() from the ensembldb package.

I run the command iteratively using a `for () {}` structure, and upon each iteration it will return RED output that is more of "progress" messages that output regardless of the success/failure of the command, not warning messages:

```
Checking CDS and protein sequence lengths ... 1/1 OK

Fetching CDS for 1 proteins ... 1 found
```

or:

```
Fetching CDS for 1 proteins ... 1 found

Checking CDS and protein sequence lengths ... 0/0 OK
```

How do I suppress these messages? Other questions I found do not seem to apply to these and their solutions do not seem to stop these. I have tried all the solutions presented in:

[Suppress output of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723034/suppress-output-of-a-function)

I have tired:

```
capture.output(for (x in length(DF)) { 
        OutputDF <- function(DF[x])
})
```

and:

```
sink(for (x in length(DF)) { 
        OutputDF <- function(DF[x])
})
```

also tried:

```
hush=function(code){
  sink("NUL") # use /dev/null in UNIX
  tmp = code
  sink()
  return(tmp)
}
hush(for (x in length(DF)) { 
        OutputDF <- function(DF[x])
})
```

also, the reason I use for and not `lapply()` is because I check whether or not the `OutputDF` is empty, and take action accordingly using an `if(){}else{}` command within the `for(){}` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
suppressMessages(proteinToGenome(...))
```

Where the arguments you are using in the model replace `...`

Comment: No, that also didnt work :/

Comment: @SkyScraper - looks like those are all printed with `message()` so using `suppressMessages()` wrapped around the call to `proteinToGenome()` should work.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much! So there are 3 different kinds of output?
Messages, error messages, and output messages? Is taht right? or are there more technical terms? @DaveArmstrong

Comment: I think of them by how you trigger them.  There is a `message()` function, a `warning()` function and then a `stop()` function (which throws an error).  You can use `suppressMessages()` and `suppressWarnings()` to stop those kinds of output. You can also print output with `print()` or `cat()` which are would likely be suppressed in the ways you tried in your original post.

Comment: so print output acts in a similar fashion as warnings but messages are unique?
Sorry, Ive never written scripts with message() or warning() >-<" I usually use print to output any information I want the script to inform me about...