# How to suppress output in RStudio?

Tags: r, printing, statistics, rstudio, rgui

I need to suppress my output when I run my R scripts in RStudio.  There are a lot of comments in my scripts, and the comments are printed when I run the file.

I realize that others have asked how to do this from the command prompt - [How to suppress output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501895/how-to-suppress-output-in-r). I'm not interested in that.

I just want to know how to suppress the output in RStudio.  The only exception to this should be `print` statements.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use source instead of source with echo in R Studio.
[image: Source in RStudio]

Same in MAC.

[image]

Comment: I don't see this option using RStudio 1.0.136 on a Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+Shift+S will do the trick. In mac, it will be Shift+Command+S.