# R studio console suddenly does not show output

Tags: r, rstudio

here are my console output examples

[image]

as you see, there are no output values when using r studio console.
Actually, there are many related issues about this, but no clear solutions. Only a temporal or Adhoc solution like: restart R or using r notebook script.
Anyway, this phenomenon happens just 1 day ago, with the same code, same operations.

At the first time, console works and a few minutes later it doesn't work.
It is so annoying me to restart or run r notebook script...
Is anybody have the same issues as me?

(I cannot give reproducible data, because it works well the other's computer)

Comment: Sometimes, whenever it happens to me, I try to use `print`, in your case `print(temp[which(temp>=0)]` (which it is a pain, I know). It could also be that you have disabled the `echo`: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097426/how-to-suppress-output-in-rstudio

Comment: It's a long shot but If you put `print(temp[...])`?

Comment: @JonnyCrunch At this time print() doesn't work.....

Comment: @Sotos same as above...

Comment: Sometimes, I have the same problem. I just removed and installed my RStudio. However, this error persists (I faced this error on two or three different PCs). I think that it might be a bug on the RStudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the gear icon beside knit and make sure that "chunk output in console" is enabled.