# Suppress automatic output to console in R

Tags: r, output

The function `callmultmoments` computes moments of the normal distribution.
The function automatically prints `"Sum of powers is odd. Moment is 0."` if the sume of the powers is odd. Is there any way to supress that under the condition that the original function should stay untouched.

Ex:

```
require(symmoments)
# Compute the moment for the 4-dimensional moment c(1,1,3,4):

m.1134 <- callmultmoments(c(1,1,3,4))
```

EDIT:

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501895/how-to-suppress-output?noredirect=1&lq=1) we can use

```
## Windows
sink("nul") 
...
sink()

## UNIX
sink("/dev/null")    # now suppresses
....                 # do stuff
sink()               # to undo prior suppression, back to normal now
```

However, I am writing a package so I want it to be platform independent. Any ideas what to do instead?

Comment: Maybe `invisible`

Comment: No invisible does not do the trick.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The issue is due to the fact that the function has multiple `print` statements, where `stop`, `warning`, or `message` would have been appropriate so that people can use `suppressWarnings` or `suppressMessages`.

You can work arount it using `invisible(capture.output())` *around your whole assignment* (not just the right side).

```r
f1 <- function(n, ...){
    print("Random print statement")
    cat("Random cat statement\n")
    rnorm(n = n, ...)
}

f1(2)
#> [1] "Random print statement"
#> Random cat statement
#> [1] -0.1115004 -1.0830523
invisible(capture.output(x <- f1(2)))
x
#> [1]  0.0464493 -0.1453540
```

See also [suppress messages displayed by "print" instead of "message" or "warning" in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8797314/2563804).

Comment: Thanks for this answer @hplieninger. Could you elaborate why we need `invisible(...)` around the `capture.output` call? I have tried it with and without in a loop, and there is no obvious difference. Just trying to work out what they are doing, and the `?` files aren't clear in this situation. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. It's a hack, and it may well be possible that I got it from one of the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797314/suppress-messages-displayed-by-print-instead-of-message-or-warning-in-r#comment10975639_8797387) in the linked thread. But without `invisible()`, the `print()` and `cat()` statements above will not be suppressed.

Comment: Hm, that's why I ask; in my loop `print()` and `cat()` are suppressed regardless of whether I use `invisible` or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the function you are using is `Barnard::barnard.test` the following works:

```
invisible(capture.output(abc <- barnard.test(8,14,1,3)))
```

But if you use just the `invisible` or just the `capture.output` functions, you still have the unwanted printing.

Warning: if you do it the way I suggest, do not later print `abc`.  You will get a lot of stuff you don't want.  Rather, just grab the parts you really want, for example `abc$p.value`.

Answer (score -1):

This message from callmultmoments can be suppressed by simply avoiding a moment that is not even. Any odd central moment, such as `c(1,1,3,4)` as in your example will have an expected value of 0 mathematically. That is, the expected value of a CENTRAL moment such as `E[X^1 Y^1 Z^3 W^4]`, where the sum of powers, such as 1+1+3+4, is odd is automatically 0.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But in my function many moments get calculated and I don’t know beforehand if they are even or odd. If you ever get around to updating the package consider changing the way the „warning“ is generated from a print statement to a proper warning statement using warning(). Like that suppressing it is much easier.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep it in mind, although at this point I don't have plans for a revision.