# Suppress console output from Keras in R

Tags: r, keras

I am trying to use an R-script in a docker environment to do some classification on the input that I am piping to it.
The script should only print the output of the classification, however I always get `Using TensorFlow backend.` as output of the first line where a function of Keras is called.

I made a small working example.

```
library(keras)

v <- (c(1,2,3))
print(v)
vCat<-to_categorical(v)
```

I want to display this as output:

```
[1] 1 2 3
```

I get however

```
[1] 1 2 3
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

So I searched around on google and stackoverflow about `sink` and `suppress...` and other stuff, from for example [Suppress automatic output to console in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499400/suppress-automatic-output-to-console-in-r), [Suppress one command's output in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723034/suppress-one-commands-output-in-r) and [Suppress automatic output to console in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499400/suppress-automatic-output-to-console-in-r). I then tried the following piece of code:

```
library(keras, quietly = T)

v <- (c(1,2,3))
print(v) 
sink("/dev/null")
capture.output(suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
vCat<-to_categorical(v) ))), file = "/dev/null")
sink()
```

This still doesn't suppress the `Using TensorFlow backend.` message. The script is called in a docker environment using littler, from the command line: `r test.R`. 
Note: when just running the script in Rstudio I don't get the message.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems standard behavior, for which other people have been complaining, too, but without a resolution so far: ["Using X backend." always printed to stdout](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1406)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Keras issue (i.e. not an R or Tensorflow one) and, as I have already commented, there have been several people [complaining about this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1406), but a solution has not been proposed by Keras maintainers so far.

A **hack**, as already suggested in the [issue thread above](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1406#issuecomment-389797583), is to locate the `keras/backend/__init__.py` file and comment out the [following line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/50411ccb0e7059ad2bd9286b64ffc2cda8957025/keras/backend/__init__.py#L86):

```
sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
```

Last time I checked, Keras in R only uses the Tensorflow backend, so you shouldn't need to repeat this for the other backend options in `__init__.py`.